# Accessing parent Javascript function from within iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I'm trying to access a function that would update the JQuery UI progress bar located in the parent from within the iframe page. Every time somebody clicks on a link in the iframe page I want it to update the progress bar. I've searched around for answers, and using "window.parent.FunctionName()" is the solution that is given, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work in my situation? Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** It seems to work in safari, firefox, but not in chrome???

The function that I want to access in the parent page is:

```
var percentage = 0;                                                                 

$('ul li a').one('click', updateBar);                                               

function updateBar() {
    percentage += 8;                                                                
    $('.ui-progressbar-value').stop().animate({ width: percentage+"%" }, 500)       
    $('.middle').progressbar('option','value', percentage);                         

    if(percentage > 100) {                                                  
        $('ui-progressbar-value').stop().animate({ width: "100%"}, 500);            
    }
}
```

The JQuery call that I'm calling from the iframe page is:

```
$('#sidenav ul li a').one('click', window.parent.updateBar);
```

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as its parent?

Comment: Yes, the are in the same domain. It doesn't seem to work in Chrome??

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? Chrome + FF are more or less identical in the way this kind of thing works

Comment: @David Kemp, I'm getting this error from the Chrome JavaScript console: 

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file://wslash/Users/W/Sites/webready/index.html# from frame with URL file://wslash/Users/W/Sites/webready/left/section1.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: @leetou - can you try running it from a web server? Browsers behave (sometimes subtly) differently when browsing files from disk.

Comment: @David Kemp, That worked. I didn't figure that the browser would behave differently on and off the server. I'll have to keep that in the back of my mind whenever these issues come up. Thanks!

Comment: @leetou glad to be of help: IE makes it very apparently that it behaves differently, but firefox and chrome (in my experience) have slightly strange behaviour when using the file:// protocol. If it's going to be deployed to a web server, develop it against a web server (even if only you can see that webserver). There are some really lightweight servers you can setup quite easily for dev use.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#sidenav ul li a').one('click',function(){

 window.parent.updateBar();

});
```

Comment: That's basically the same end result as what the OP already tried, written slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

1. be sure that jQuery is also embedded inside the frame
2. Your approach as it is should work, but the context where the function is executed is the parent window.
      If you like to execute the function using the frame as context, provide the context as argument:

---

```
 function updateBar(context) {
    percentage += 8;                                                                
    $('.ui-progressbar-value',context).stop().animate({ width: percentage+"%" }, 500)       
    $('.middle',context).progressbar('option','value', percentage);                         

    if(percentage > 100) {                                                  
        $('ui-progressbar-value',context).stop().animate({ width: "100%"}, 500);            
    }
}
```

---

```
$('#sidenav ul li a').one('click', function(){window.parent.updateBar(document);});
```